# how to remove all /etc/*.txt files with puppet

Tags: puppet

this puppet manifest will remove the file `/etc/file.txt` if it exists:

```
  file { "/etc/file.txt":
    ensure  => absent,
  }
```

how to tell puppet to remove all files `/etc/*.txt`?

according to the reference, it seems that `puppet file` does not allow wildcards.
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/file.html

ps: I am aware that I could execute a script from puppet, but I would prefer another more elegant way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a built-in type for this called 'tidy', which allows you to specify a file glob pattern of files to remove.

Check it out at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/tidy.html.

Comment: Looks nice, my own use case was to wipe a root directory and in that case tidy took forever to traverse all the files(about 1gig worth of many small files) before finally removing the directory. I ended falling back to an exec with a rm -fr

Comment: The documentation seems buggy as putting 0 to the age does not delete all files as specified. Giving a working example would make that answer more useful.

Comment: Thanks, this has been useful. I tried ChatGPT to get answer for this but I was getting suggestion to use `rm -rf`, so I resorted to our stackoverflow champions.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a glob pattern with tidy: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/tidy.html

So this would be your solution:

```
tidy { "delete-txt-files-in-etc":
    path    => "/etc",
    recurse => true,
    matches => [ '*.txt' ],
    rmdirs  => false,
}
```

Comment: This works, except you have to set recurse to `true` when using `matches`: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#tidy-attribute-matches

Comment: +1 for giving an example without `age`. In the documentation they said to put '0' for deleting all files but in my case I just had to remove the `age` otherwise it does not delete any file.

Comment: @falconizer you're right, note that you can edit the answer so that it would work for any person.